# Reverse a list in scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, reverse, sicp, mit-scheme

I'm trying to reverse a list in scheme and I came up with to the following solution:

```
(define l (list 1 2 3 4))

(define (reverse lista)
    (car (cons (reverse (cdr (cons 0 lista))) 0)))

(display (reverse l))
```

Although it works I don't really understand why it works.

In my head, it would evaluate to a series of nested cons until cons of () (which the cdr of a list with one element).

I guess I am not understanding the substitution model, could someone explain me why it works?

Obs:

- It is supposed to work only in not nested lists.
- Taken form SICP, exercise 2.18.
- I know there are many similar questions, but as far as I saw, none presented 
  this solution.

Thank you

Comment: are you sure? the code you show clearly does not work, and for a good reason - "(cdr (cons 0 lista))" evaluates to "lista", so it loops endlessly. a recursive definition has to have the base case, testing for it on each step. your procedure does not have it, it always recurs. the only way I see this thing can work is by evoking builtin reverse instead, so maybe you had a typo when defining it?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the built-in reverse. I am using it, instead of my defined procedure, when I change the name it really doesnt work. Sorry for this question.

Comment: No problem! Everyone I know learning lisp made similar mistakes (me included). I decided to write the answer anyway. Good luck and happy hacking, I hope you enjoy scheming!

Answer (score 1):

This reads pretty much the same as the solutions in other languages:

- if the list is empty, return an empty list.  Otherwise ...
- chop off the first element (CAR)
- reverse the remainder of the list (CDR)
- append (CONS) the first element to that reversal
- return the result

Now ... given my understanding from LISP days, the code would look more like this:

```
(append (reverse (cdr lista)) (list (car lista)))
```

... which matches my description above.

Comment: CAR = grab the head element; CDR = grab the rest of the list; CONS = append; 0 = NULL.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I understand that, but what about (define (reverse l) (cons (reverse (cdr l)) 0)). There's no car and it still returns the reversed list (less the first element). If instead of 0 I had (car l) that would be ok according to what you said. But I don't visualize how it happens without car.

Comment: In truth, I don't quite see how your given code works; I speak LISP, rather than Scheme.  From what I know, **cons (0 x)** returns simply **x**, so *my* reading says that this will go into infinite recursion.

Comment: I am sorry, my code doesnt work at all. I was using builtin reverse and getting confused about the results. It's solved now. Thank you and sorry.

Comment: @Prune this is incorrect, cons creates a pair (so assuming "x" is e.g. "42", "(cons 0 x)" evaluates to "(0 . 42)", not "42" itself), and what you want in the case of your code snippet is "append", which concatenates list, so "(append (reverse (cdr lista)) (list (car lista)))". Also be careful with notation: opening paren goes before operand, not after.

Comment: @dercz Thanks; fixed the code.  Now, if *you* want to post the correct answer and include whatever of mine you'd like to use, we can give you proper credit and delete this one.

Comment: @Prune I think my answer suffices (the question was "why does it work"). And your answer is a very nice hint to anyone trying to implement reverse without tail recursion. I'd leave it all as it is...

Comment: Ah ... I didn't refresh the page, apparently, and it looked like mine was the only answer.  Yes, let's let them both stand.

Answer (score 1):

[As this happens quite often, I write the answer anyway]

Scheme implementations do have their builtin versions of reverse, map, append etc. as they are specified in RxRS (e.g. https://www.cs.indiana.edu/scheme-repository/R4RS/r4rs_8.html).

In the course of learning scheme (and actually any lisp dialect) it's really valuable to implement them anyway. The danger is, one's definition can collide with the built-in one (although e.g. scheme's define or lisp's label should shadow them). Therefore it's always worth to call this hand-made implementation with some other name, like "my-reverse", "my-append" etc. This way you will save yourself much confusion, like in the following:

```
(let ([append
        (lambda (xs ys)
          (if (null? xs)
              ys
              (cons (car xs) (append (cdr xs) ys))))])
 (append '(hello) '(there!)))
```

-- this one **seems** to work, creating a **false impression** that "let" works the same as "letrec". But just change the name to "my-append" and it breaks, because at the moment of evaluating the lambda form, the symbol "my-append" is not yet bound to anything (unlike "append" which was defined as a builtin procedure).

Of course such let form will work in a language with dynamic scoping, but scheme is lexical (with the exception of "define"s), and the reason is referential transparency (but that's so far offtopic that I can only refer interested reader to one of the lambda papers http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/ai-lab-pubs/AIM-453.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. Here is another:

```
(define my-reverse
  (lambda (lst)
    (define helper
      (lambda (lst result)
        (if (null? lst)
            result
            (helper (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) result)))))
    (helper lst '())))
```